# Issue Using Results of a Query in Access Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
SELECT ProductData.ShiftStart, ProductData.ExtrusionLine, Avg(ProductData.RollDensity) AS AvgOfRollDensity, StDev(ProductData.RollDensity) AS StDevOfRollDensity
FROM ProductData
GROUP BY ProductData.ShiftStart, ProductData.ExtrusionLine
HAVING (((ProductData.ShiftStart)=[Forms]![RollRelease]![ShiftStart]) AND ((ProductData.ExtrusionLine)=[Forms]![RollRelease]![Line]));
```

If I open the form "RollRelease", enter data, and then run "qryRollDensity" with "RollRelease" open the query works. When I try use the query through a select statement I get mismatch errors or missing parameter errors etc. Ultimately I need the value of AvgOfRollDensity and StDevOfRollDensity in my form so I can do some calculations.

Comment: You are depending on values inside the Form. Therefore you must have the form open and filled. `HAVING (((ProductData.ShiftStart)=[Forms]![RollRelease]![ShiftStart]) AND ((ProductData.ExtrusionLine)=[Forms]![RollRelease]![Line]));`

Comment: I stated that when I have the form open the query works.

Comment: Use WHERE instead of HAVING to filter records before aggregation. Why are you pulling from query with SELECT? Exactly where are you doing that? An option is to use domain aggregate functions in textboxes on form; either DLookup() expressions on the query or DAvg() and DStDev() on raw data table with the WHERE criteria.

Comment: Your question makes it seem that you are confused as to why it doesnt work when the form is closed. The query should always work as long as the form is opened and filled. If you want that to be different, you must remove dependency from the form. A dirty fix is to use the form and save the values you need on a table, then select this table values in your query and not the form. But you still have to open the form at some point to have those values updated. Is the ShiftStart manually entered? how about Line? we cant help much without knowing where that comes from.

Comment: If I open the form and enter data, then run the query independently of the form while the form is open, I get the expected results.

Comment: What I want to do is use the results of the query, AvgOfRollDensuty and StDevOfRollDensity in the VBA code of the form.

Comment: I don't "have" to use a query. It is the option I started with.

Comment: So what happens? Error message about missing parameters? Did you read my previous comment about domain aggregate functions? Dynamic query parameters will not carry through to VBA recordset SQL statement.

Comment: @June7 I am exploring DAvg().

Comment: Not necessary to specify Value property. It is the default for data controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use WHERE instead of HAVING to filter records before aggregation.

Dynamic query parameters will not carry through to VBA recordset SQL statement.

An option is to use domain aggregate functions in textboxes on form; either DLookup() expressions on the query or DAvg() and DStDev() on raw data table with the WHERE criteria. Assuming ShiftStart and ExtrusionLine are text type fields:

```
=DAvg("[RollDensity]", "ProductData", "[ShiftStart] = '" & Me.ShiftStart & "' AND [ExtrusionLine] = '" & Me.Line & "'"
```

```
=DStDev("[RollDensity]", "ProductData", "[ShiftStart] = '" & Me.ShiftStart & "' AND [ExtrusionLine] = '" & Me.Line & "'"
```

Otherwise, remove apostrophes and instead use # delimiter for date/time field and no delimiter for number type.

Comment: I get a "Data type mismatch in criteria expression error." using your statements. ShiftStart is Date/Time and Line is a number.

Comment: Then remove apostrophes and use # for date/time field.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do is use the results of the query, AvgOfRollDensuty
> and StDevOfRollDensity in the VBA code of the form. – Thomas Heikkila

Well that settles it, in the form, any button or event you want to call you can use this code:

```
Dim db as Database, rs as Recordset, SQL as String, AVGRollDen as Variant, STDevRollDen as Variant
Set db = CurrentDb
SQL = "SELECT ProductData.ShiftStart, ProductData.ExtrusionLine, Avg(ProductData.RollDensity) AS AvgOfRollDensity, StDev(ProductData.RollDensity) AS StDevOfRollDensity " & _
"FROM ProductData " & _
"GROUP BY ProductData.ShiftStart, ProductData.ExtrusionLine " & _
"HAVING (((ProductData.ShiftStart)='" & Me.ShiftStart & "') AND ((ProductData.ExtrusionLine)='" & Me.Line & "'));" 
'Big chance you will have to change the Me.ShiftStart and Me.Line to Me.Text## that has the value. Also, I am calling "Me." because this is supposed to run somewhere in your Form Code. If these values are numbers, remove the ' (apostrophes) from the line above.

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL)
If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
    'Records Returned
    rs.MoveFirst
    AVGRollDen = rs.Fields(2).Value
    STDevRollDen = rs.Fields(3).Value
    'Now AVGRollDen and STDevRollDen has the values you want
Else
    'No records returned
End If
rs.Close
db.Close
Set rs = nothing
Set db = nothing
```

Comment: With some modification, this could be a custom function called from textbox to return a value. Pass an argument to define whether to return Avg or Dev then use a conditional to determine which calc to return.

Comment: I am sure this would work but I got @June7's answer to work.